# APEX: Write list to body of note

Tags: apex

I am trying to write the results from a database.saveresult to a note. I am trying to figure out how to take the list of values and pass them to the note body field. I am getting a list to string error which I understand but I don't know how to convert the list into a string of values.

Any help? Problem code is right at end of code.

```
//Session
        for (Database.SaveResult sr : srSession) {
            if (sr.isSuccess()) {
                // Operation was successful, so get the ID of the record that was processed
                System.debug('Successfully transfered session. Session ID: ' + sr.getId());
                showRecords = FALSE;
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, 'Successfully transferred Sessions. Session ID: ' + sr.getId()));

            }
            else {
                // Operation failed, so get all errors                
                for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                    showRecords = FALSE;
                    sessionSuccess = FALSE;
                    System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
                    System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
                    System.debug('Session fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
                    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage()));

                }
            }
        }

        if(taskSuccess == TRUE){
            //create note
            note n = new note();
            n.ParentId = empSession.Employee__c;
            n.Title = 'Task Transfer Record';
            n.Body = srSession;
            Insert n;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way if you're just doing this for debugging would be to dump it into JSON (serialize the srSession object).

```
    if(taskSuccess){
        //create note
        note n = new note();
        n.ParentId = empSession.Employee__c;
        n.Title = 'Task Transfer Record';
        n.Body = JSON.serializePretty(srSession);
        Insert n;
    }
```

If you're trying to summarize the save results, you can build a string during your iterations and use that as the body.

```
//Session
    String outputResult = '';
    for (Database.SaveResult sr : srSession) {
        if (sr.isSuccess()) {
            // Operation was successful, so get the ID of the record that was processed
            System.debug('Successfully transfered session. Session ID: ' + sr.getId());
            showRecords = FALSE;
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, 'Successfully transferred Sessions. Session ID: ' + sr.getId()));
            outputResult += '\nSuccessfully transferred Sessions.  Session ID: ' + sr.getId();

        }
        else {
            // Operation failed, so get all errors                
            for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                showRecords = FALSE;
                sessionSuccess = FALSE;
                System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
                System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
                System.debug('Session fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage()));

            }
        }
    }

    if(taskSuccess){
        //create note
        note n = new note();
        n.ParentId = empSession.Employee__c;
        n.Title = 'Task Transfer Record';
        n.Body = outputResult;
        Insert n;
    }
```

Comment: Also note the if statement, the == TRUE is repetitive.  Anything inside the if is already boolean evaluated.